# Is there a way to render/show ACAD drawing in ArcMap correctly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, convert, autocad

I would like to extract only certain lines from an ACAD drawing but it seems that a lot of lines are being dropped when the dwg drawng is viewed and rendered in ArcMap. (see below)  **Is it possible to view an autocad drawing in ArcMap the same way it is rendered in AutoCAD or TurboCAD.**

Intersection as viewed in TurboCAD:[image]

Same file and the same intersection viewed in ArcMAP:
[image]

In ArcMap when converted to FGDB Feature Class:
[image]

Comment: What you are seeing is a technology race. Some of the drawing objects are probably civil 3d objects. Esri doesn't display them correctly yet. Any open source converters sre going to have the same problem. FME is the only one I know of that keeps up with both. $$ the originator could perhaps bridge to landxml. I dont know where you would go from there but it woildnt be so proprietary.

Comment: Following along what Brad mentions, and going with the dxf route in the answer, and not knowing TurboCAD... Some of the newer/complex objects in AutoDesk formats have always given other software trouble. Sometimes it's helpful to use one of AutoDesk's free viewers (like TrueView, for example) to save an older file format version or dxf file to then try with the other software. That gives you (theoretically) AutoDesk's native reading and conversion of their objects/formats down to something older/dumbed-down and likely to be more universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am doing in such cases is basically exporting every layer separately. Then import them all to any gis software. If you have auto cad map, it can export shp-s, for example, keeping layers in separate files. Then you also have to style every layer properly in gis.

If you don't have auto cad MAP, you can save each layer to dxf, and import that to esri. You don't have to do every single one separately, just the ones that need to be nicely symbolized.

I figure you were looking for quick solution, and there might be one but I haven't been able to find it yet. The problem is that ESRI and cad have different symbology logic.

If you decide to go for it this way, first thing to do is to purge the dwg.

Comment: Good Ideas, thanks. I wish I had AutoCAD with Map 3D.  My TurboCAD Deluxe does not export to shapefile but i will try the DXF approach. Even Purging is an advanced option in TurboCAD.

Comment: NP, glad if I helped. There has to be some open source way to convert dwg to shp, with some kind of options like the layer separation. Its just that I always had map, so didn't need it. I did a quick search and this page came up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409974/converting-a-cad-file-to-a-shape-file

Comment: Oh yeah. That works pretty nice!  I am able to select any part of the drawing directly in CAD, save as DXF. Best part is that doing it this way, the various saved DXF's render perfectly in ArcMap - identical to the original drawing.